# Looking for lambda invocation shorthand documentation

Tags: vb.net, lambda, syntax

I always took issue with the inability to `var` / `Dim` a variable implicitly when using a `Using` block to declare a data context which returns the initial value of the variable. For example,

```vb
Dim classifications As IEnumerable(Of RT_Classification)
Using dc As New MyDataContext
    classifications = dc.RT_Classifications.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Order).ToList()
End Using
```

the type RT_Classification must be provided explicitly when the variable is declared. Compare with `Using` not limited to the query alone

```vb
Dim classifications = dc.RT_Classifications.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Order).ToList()
```

in which you get something implicit, analogous to `var` in c#. But the data context must then contain the declaration, and encompass the entire context of the variable `classifications`, which is undesirable.

I thought of using a lambda, which basically solves the problems

```vb
Dim classifications =
    (Function()
        Using dc As New MyDataContext
            Return dc.RT_Classifications.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Order).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function).Invoke()
```

but seems a bit bulky. However, with knowledge of the `()` shorthand for `.Invoke()` and an IDE sugestion to remove `(` `)`, I came up with this strange looking, but working code

```vb
Dim classifications =
    Function()
        Using dc As New MyDataContext
            Return dc.RT_Classifications.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Order).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function()
```

Note the trailing `End Function()` which was new to me. My question is how long has this been available, and are there any downsides to using it, past potential readability issues?

Comment: In ye olden days we’d just put this in a `static`/`Shared` function. Is there a reason you’re using VB.NET instead of C#?

Comment: @Dai I understand how a static function could do the same thing. But I like to hide the function from the rest of my class if it's not useful elsewhere. I could use a local function `Dim f = Function() ... End Function` `Dim classifications = f()` which is almost the same as what I have now. We have a solution with both c# and vb.net and this project happens be in vb.net. I'm just asking about the `End Function()` syntax specifically.

Comment: This feature is commonly used with [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) and it has existed at least since lambda expressions were introduced in the VB 10.0 compiler used by VS 2010. Note that `End Function()` isn't a special kind of syntax. It is exactly equivalent to if you were to wrap the entire expression in parentheses, or simply your call to `f()`.

Comment: @VisualVincent I can accept that, I guess I just never thought to write it like this. I had wrapped the function in `(` `)()` but my VS2019 suggested I remove the wrapping parentheses. Didn't expect that. But it's good to know this syntactic sugar exists. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I actually didn't know it existed either. But I understand the basics about what the compiler does with its lambda expressions, and could therefore conclude what was actually going on. As we all know, VB.NET is very laidback when it comes to writing your code ;). -- TL;DR: The compiler basically only sees `ThisIsADelegate()`, which then calls the `Invoke` method on that just like when you do `f()`.

Comment: And it suggested to change `(ThisIsADelegateVariable)()` to `ThisIsADelegateVariable()`. Makes perfect sense. Thanks again

Comment: @VisualVincent it's interesting that the single line `Dim f = (Function() 1)()` can't be simplified further. If it's expanded into a multi-line with a `Return` then we have the `End Function` which the parentheses can sit next to nicely. Are you able to confirm this works with the 2010 compiler by any chance?

Comment: No, I mean `End Function()`. I know how silly `Function() 1()` is :P

Comment: Oh, yes. That works in VB 10.0 as well (I highly suspected it would, and I just tried it to be sure).

Comment: @Dai I can't speak for djv, but I prefer VB to C#.  I'm fluent in both.

Comment: @Craig pretty much the same here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `End Function()` isn't a special kind of syntax. It is exactly equivalent to your call to `f()`, or if you were to wrap the entire expression in parentheses.

Prior to parsing the `()` shorthand, the compiler compiles the entire lambda expression, moves it to a separate method and replaces it in your code with a delegate pointing to that method. So when the compiler resumes parsing your code, all it sees is something along the lines of: `ThisIsADelegate()`.

This becomes apparent if you decompile your application using a tool like [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy).

Original code:

```
Public Class TheseAreLambdas
    Dim values As String() = {"This", "word", "is", "the", "longest"}

    Dim classifications =
        Function()
            Return values.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Length).ToList()
        End Function()

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        'I used DirectCast just to reduce mess in the decompiled code. Not necessary otherwise.
        MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(classifications, List(Of String)).Count.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Decompiled code:

```cs
public class TheseAreLambdas
{
    private string[] values;
    private object classifications;

    public TheseAreLambdas()
    {
        /*
            All variable initializations are automatically moved to the constructor.
        */

        //Our array of values.
        values = new string[5]
        {
            "This",
            "word",
            "is",
            "the",
            "longest"
        };

        //Our lambda expression, moved to a method called "_Lambda$__1", wrapped in
        //a compiler-generated delegate and invoked on the spot (notice the parenthesis on the end).
        classifications = new VB$AnonymousDelegate_1<List<string>>(_Lambda$__1)();
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((List<string>)classifications).Count.ToString());
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private List<string> _Lambda$__1() //Our lambda expression used for the "classifications" variable.
    {
        return values.OrderBy((string s) => s.Length).ToList();
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private static int _Lambda$__2(string s)
    {
        return s.Length;
    }
}
```